# Conversion from Long to Double in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

Is there any way to convert a `Long` data type to `Double` or `double`?

For example, I need to convert `15552451L` to a `double` data type.

Answer (score 162):

You could simply do :

```
double d = (double)15552451L;
```

Or you could get double from Long object as :

```
Long l = new Long(15552451L);
double d = l.doubleValue();
```

Comment: Don't need any string parsing there: `Long.valueOf(15552451L).doubleValue()` if you want to go via `Long`. Note this is the same, internally, as the cast from a `double`, except that you're doing some auto/unboxing.

Comment: I did. Parsing a string to do this (now edited out of the answer) will degrade performance by many orders of magnitude. Boxing is less expensive but still worth avoiding, especially in cases like this (using `new`) where it can't be elided away.

Comment: I think the example was supposed to show that you can get from Long -> double. How the Long was initialised doesn't seem that important..

Comment: Granted the example in the answer looks more reasonable now having been edited. I maintain that conversion from a value to a double via a String is not good practice. I would have thought that to be fairly uncontroversial.

Comment: My 2nd example is just showing how to get double value , if you have Long object. If you just had number , why would you assign long value to double by casting ? You could very well assign value directly as double.

Comment: @jjk If you look at question , it does mention converting from Long (object) to double. I don't understand what is your stand on this and what's the controversy.

Comment: You do not need to cast explicitly. It just works: `double d = 15552451L;`

Answer (score 24):

Simple casting?

```
double d = (double)15552451L;
```

Comment: And if its a literal just `15552451d`

Comment: I even think a cast is not necessary, you can create a double with a long value like this: "double d = 1234L;".

Comment: Probably not - but the question is basic enough to warrant the introduction of a concept like casting.

Answer (score 12):

As already mentioned, you can simply cast long to double. But be **careful** with long to double conversion because long to double is a **narrowing conversion** in java.

[Conversion from type double to type long requires a nontrivial translation from a 64-bit floating-point value to the 64-bit integer representation. Depending on the actual run-time value, information may be lost.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

e.g. following program will print 1 not 0

```
    long number = 499999999000000001L;
    double converted = (double) number;
    System.out.println( number - (long) converted);
```

Comment: Your link says the opposite, that *double to long* is a narrowing conversion, while long to double is widening

Comment: Formally, long->double is not narrowing, but this conversion can still loose precision: "A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4). " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: (continued) `(long) converted` is not a good illustration of the answer as double -> long is a narrowing conversion and `number - (long) converted` should not always give 0 by definition https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3

Comment: @Antonio, Didn't get you. Do we get some non-zero digits after point(.) in the resulting float/double? Is that what we mean by losing the "precision" of int/long?

Comment: @Sriman No, no non-zero digits after point(.) in the resulting float/double should be expected: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2   However, you can still see non-zero digits after point(.) due the IEEE 745 format specifics and due to printf formatting options (but this is not related to the "precision loss").

Comment: @Antonio ok. Then what does precision mean for int/long?

Comment: @Sriman Consider the following example. Both LONG and DOUBLE have 8 bytes. However, DOUBLE is much more complex than LONG, it has mantissa and exponent parts and is interpreted differently, see IEEE 754. Hence, DOUBLE has less value space to represent integer numbers. For example, 499999999000000001L will not be represented exactly in DOUBLE (see the answer which we comment on). If you care about precision, you should use BigDecimal to represent LONG values as floating point numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for the binary conversion?

```
double result = Double.longBitsToDouble(15552451L);
```

This will give you the `double` with the same bit pattern as the provided `long`.

Binary or hexadecimal literals will come in handy, here. Here are some examples.

```
double nan = Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000001L);
double positiveInfinity = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L);
double negativeInfinity = Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L);
```

(See [Double.longBitsToDouble(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)))

You also can get the `long` back with

```
long bits = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.NaN);
```

(See [Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)))

Comment: This does something else, see the jdoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long))

Comment: Yes. But he did not specify *how* he wants to convert `long` to `double` (I think casting is one of the first things you learn when using Java) nor did he accept any answer. Maybe he wants to get a `double` with the same bit pattern as the `long` value. Well, I don't know. So I just gave the answer.

Comment: I added additional information, so the answer is more valuable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Long i = 1000000;
String s = i + "";
Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
Float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
```

This way we can convert Long type to Double or Float or Int without any problem because it's easy to convert string value to Double or Float or Int.

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by a **long date** type?

You can cast a long to a double:

```
double d = (double) 15552451L;
```

Comment: I guess that a long date would be something like "Tuesday, 19 September 24893243092333".

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
long x = somevalue;

double y = Double.longBitsToDouble(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good for you.

`BigDecimal.valueOf([LONG_VALUE]).doubleValue()`

How about this code?
:D