# How do I format 2 long values into percentage formats?

Tags: java, long-integer, percentage

Consider this situation.

I have 2 long variables a and b.
I'm trying to get percentage in these formats:

xx.x and 0.xx.

I've tried casting both to double and dividing but I'm not getting in the latter format.

Comment: Can you rephrase a bit?

Comment: Do you  mean `100 * a / b` rounded to the 3 most significant digits?

Comment: The double result has to be formatted in those formats. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Duplicate? Long to Double : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724830/conversion-from-long-to-double-in-java / Number Formatting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
long a = 12, d = 34;
double ratio = a / (double) d;
DecimalFormat ratioFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
DecimalFormat percentFormat= new DecimalFormat("#.#%");
System.out.println("ratio = " + ratioFormat.format(ratio));
System.out.println("percent = " + percentFormat.format(ratio));
```

Which outputs :

```
ratio = 0.35
percent = 35.3%
```

Comment: Thanks @zakinster.
This worked for me.

Using the solution in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738853/java-decimal-format-parse-to-return-double-value-with-specified-number-of-deci 
I was able to parse the result to a double variable.