# Convert long time into Double

Tags: java, type-conversion, double, long-integer

I was trying to convert my long time into Double but failed, I am trying to figure out how to do it.
I used the code to convert my time into Double in question:
[Conversion from Long to Double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724830/conversion-from-long-to-double-in-java)
but I still receive

incompatible types: long cannot be converted to Double

error.

This is the code I am using:

```
LTime = (Double)handle.getTimestamp().getTime();
```

and

```
time1 = handle.getTimestamp().getTime();
LTime = (Double)time1;
```

What should I do to convert long to Double? I really want some help on it.

Comment: `(Double)` != `(double)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Long lng1 = 1000L;
Double dbl2 = (double) lng1.longValue();
```

The type `Long` contains a value of the `long` primitive type, which you can access by calling `longValue()`. Then you can cast this value to the `double` primitive type. Using the `double` value, you can create a `Double` object.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: .longValue() is unnecessary unboxing. Double dbl2 = (double) lng1; will work

Comment: @HoRn That works too I guess. Thanks.